# WSO2 - Micro Integrator is not connecting to the API Manager's SERVICE CATALOG

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-integrator

Something similar is happening to me. I'm quite new in WSO2 world.

On the same server I have installed:

wso2am-4.1.0 --> API Manager executed as linux service (api-manager.sh) wso2ei-7.1.0 --> Micro Integrator and dashboard , both exec. as linux services. MI is the last one to load.

I'm not using the embedded micro-integration of the API Mgr due it hasn't got any dataservice features (and I don't know how to enable them, by the way..)

Under Micro Integrator (wso2ei-7.1.0)'s conf/deployment.toml file, I have this section:

```
[[service_catalog]]
apim_host = "https://localhost:9443"
enable = true
username = "xxxxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxxxx"
```

BUT,no integrated service published to the service catalog. ALSO, under Micro Integrator's LOG I didn't see any statement like : "Succesfully updated the Service Catalog" nor error msg..

Any help? Thanks in advance! Daniel

I tried changing the conf file settings,  service url, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service catalog feature is only available in MI 4.x versions.

You can manually create the API in the API Manager by importing the OpenAPI(Swagger) definition.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that based on Joy's recommendation. Thanks for you support

Answer (score 0):

In order to use API Manager's Service Catalog feature, both API Manager and Micro-integrator should be on the same version.

You need to use Micro-integrator 4.1.0 along with API Manager 4.1.0 to use this capability.

Comment: Thanks Joy.  I did that and it is fully working. Thanks for you support